# Is it possible to use firebase to serve a very high number of different child projects?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Basically I need to create a main app to be used as main entry point for my customers, each customer from here shoud be able to manage the contents of their apps and websites, expenses and many infos.

I have a question that seems noone could answer, I tried to read around but I found only limited answers.

I'm working on a Angular 8 & firestore project that would need to have a main database, authentication and hosting, 'till here no issues at all, the problem is that this main project should serve hundred and hundred of different websites and apps, I cannot find the way how all of this should be organized.

I know I can add multiple projects on the same account but it looks like there are very small limits, something like 36 websites and 8 or 10 different projects connected to the same instance.

Is there a way to use firebase and all its functionalities to serve a very high amount of child projects... again not 2, 30 or 50 but hundreds or thousands.

Each child project should NOT share the same authentication, I mean an user could be authenticate in the main project but NOT in each single child project, to let you understand, imagine a central app where to store informations of 2000 hotels, then each hotel should have it's own app, it's own website and its own subscribers, it should have the main dashboard, cms and services into the main app.

On the other hands tha main App should collect informations from all children apps, it should store all the images for all children apps in the main hosting and store all expensives and all purchases from customers in all 2000 hotels, everything on a single database, do you understand what I mean?

This wouldn't be so difficult to achieve using the usual mysql in a serverfull app but I cannot understand how to manage this using firebase.

If someone could have some info about this please let me know, thank you!!!

Comment: There can be only one instance of Cloud Firestore for a given project.  Firebase projects are not very good at multi-tenancy.  The usual advice is for each app to have its own dedicated project so it can be isolated from the others.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/hHHGM50m-g8

Comment: I know the limit of the single instance that's why I was looking for a way to get the result using a single instance, even if I should create a different system to login users into child apps not based on firebase authentication... I did already something but if there are better solutions I woule be happy to hear. I understand firebase is not very good for multi-tenancy but I still hope to find a work around.